# Unable to format date properly

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, simpledateformat

I have an issue with formatting the date.
In my addstudent.jsp file I am asking user ti enter their date of birth. This I am doing using input type="text".Add the format to enter is dd-mm-yyyy. Now I have to store the date in yyyy-mm-dd format as mysql stores in yyyy-mm-dd format. 
I did this in addprocess.jsp file. But something is wrong which I do not understand. When I give 08-05-2009 as input, I am getting 2009-01-08
 as output to store in mysql database. What am I doing wrong?
This is my addstudent.jsp file.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Adding Student</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    function validateform(){
    var errorString="";
    var name=document.myform.name.value;
    var email=document.myform.email.value;
    var parentemail=document.myform.parentemail.value;

    if (name==null || name=="" || !(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(name))){  
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=errorString+"Name can have    only alphabets and spaces"; 
    return false;  
    }
   function validateEmail(email){
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)| (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
    }
  if(!validateEmail(email)){
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=errorString+" Your email is not   valid";
    return false;
   }
 if(!validateEmail(parentemail)){
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=errorString+" Your parent's  email is not valid";
return false;
  }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
        <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
        <%@ page import="java.util.regex.*"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <div id="error"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="box">
                <form name="myform" method="post" action="addprocess.jsp"   onsubmit="return validateform();">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td style="color:navy;"><B> Login Form</B></td>   </tr>
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email Id:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email ID"/></td></tr>  
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Parent Email Id:</td><td><input type="text" name="parentemail" placeholder="Enter Parent's Email ID"/></td></tr>    
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Date Of Birth:</td><td><input type="text" name="dateofbirth" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>      </td><td><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></td></tr>

                    </table>
                </form>     

                <br>

             </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is addprocess.jsp file

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
     <body>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.regex.*"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.ParseException"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
     <%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
     %> 
     <%
      String name=request.getParameter("name");
      String email=request.getParameter("email");
      String parentemail=request.getParameter("parentemail");



    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    java.util.Date util_Date = format.parse(         request.getParameter("dateofbirth") );
    java.sql.Date dateOfBirth = new java.sql.Date( util_Date.getTime() );

    System.out.println(dateOfBirth);

    String address=request.getParameter("address");
    %> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have none of the many other Questions and Answers on the topic of storing dates in a database in Java not solved your problem? Please explain how your Question is different and novel.

Comment: @BasilBourque I stumbled upon some saying "mm" is used. I couldn't find a clear explanation for it.

Comment: And what does the class documentation say? What do the hundreds of examples in other Questions and Answers show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat not showing the right date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951911/simpledateformat-not-showing-the-right-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mm" in date formatting is minute; "MM" in date formatting is month.

Comment: thanks  was  confused between MM and mm . Got it cleared now :)